# Alternatives to using selenium XPATH to find an element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

On this website, I'm trying to find an element based on its XPATH, but the XPATH keeps changing. What's the next best alternative?

Snippet from website

```
<button class="KnkXXg vHcWfw T1alpA kiPMng AvEAGQ vM2UTA DM1_6g _-kwXsw Mqe1NA SDIrVw edrpZg" type="button" aria-expanded="true"><span class="nW7nAQ"><div class="VpIG5Q"></div></span></button>
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="__id15"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div
#Sometimes id is a number between 15-18

//*[@id="__id23"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div
#Sometimes id is a number between 13-23
```

Here's how I use the code:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="__id3"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/button"""))).click()
```

I've tried clicking the element by finding the button class, but for whatever reason it won't do anything.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "KnkXXg vHcWfw T1alpA kiPMng AvEAGQ vM2UTA DM1_6g _-kwXsw Mqe1NA SDIrVw edrpZg"))).click()
```

Comment: I would look into CSS Selectors, they can be more flexible if done right. They will not break if the component location is moved.
Using class names with children class names would allow for extracting elements without having to knew details about the hierarchy.

Comment: _I'm trying to find an element based on its XPATH, but the XPATH keeps changing._ Have you tried writing a more accurate/flexible XPath? _What's the next best alternative?_ Have you consulted the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If Part of the text is keep changing you can use contains in the xpath.

```
//*[contains(@id,"__id"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div
```